# Admin and super admin Authorization and conditional rendering using AWS Amplify + React app

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am working on Amplify + React fullstack app and have created complete Authentication flow. I want to authorize users based on their roles i.e. admin, superadmin, user, etc. When I sign up a new user, I am seeing the details in AWS Cognito but I am not able to figure out the roles for the user. I have two solutions in mind.

1. Add a userType custom attribute in User table in AWS Cognito.
2. Create three different groups in the pool and handle them manually.

I want to know which solution is better. I am unable to find any help online so it would be great if the detailed steps are shared. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cognito groups are meant for exact same use cases. you can create a group named ADMIN and in your client you may check if the signed in user is part of ADMIN group like this

```
user.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]?.includes("ADMIN")
```

Comment: Hi Anurag, thanks for sharing this. I have implemented this and it works fine. But, I also want to be able to add users to different groups from the front-end. So, whenever a user signs up from the admin sign up page, he is added to the user group on Cognito and I can then redirect redirect him/her to a different page. It would be great if you share the details regarding that as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the admin action APIs for this. Specifically have a look at addUserToGroup function here. https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin/